# Disk/Sphere Bundle of the Trivial Bundle.

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

The disk bundle of a vector bundle $p: E \to B$ is defined as :

$D(E)= \{e \in E : \|e\| \leq 1\} $ (Assuming there a norm on the space of course!) and the sphere bundle is defined to be

$S(E) =\{e \in E : \|e\|=1\}$.

I was wondering if someone could explain the following in a little more detail:

When the rank of $E$ is $0$, hence, $E=B\times ℝ^0 \cong B$,

$D(E) = E \cong B$ and $S(E) = \emptyset$.

I don't see how these follow from $E \cong B$.

Or alternatively if someone had a good reference for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what's going on, you just need to look at the fiber, which is a copy of $\mathbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$. In $\mathbb{R}^0$, there is only one vector with length less than or equal to one, namely $0$, so the closed unit disc of $\mathbb{R}^0$ is $\{0\} = \mathbb{R}^0$. On the other hand, there is no vector of length one, so the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^0$ is empty.

Comment: Since $D(E) =\{e \in E : \|e\| \leq 1\}$ surely there can be another vector in $E$ other than $0$?

Comment: That should read another element in $E$, which isn't zero and even has norm bigger than 1, since $p: E \to B$ isn't necessarily injective

Comment: My comments apply to a fiber, $E_b := p^{-1}(b) \cong \mathbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$. Do you agree that there is only one element in $\mathbb{R}^0$?

Comment: absolutely, but I don't see how that means the Disk Bundle has to be the whole space

Comment: What else could it be? There are no other elements of $E$.

Comment: Oh yeah! Because $E \cong B$ and since for each $b \in B$ there is a unique $E_b$, $E= \sqcup_{b \in B} E_b$. So $E$ is just a load of copies of $\{0\}$ so zero itself. Is my thinking right here?

Comment: I think so. Just to be clear, for each $b \in B$, we have $E_b = p^{-1}(b) = \mathbb{R}^0 = \{0_b\}$; here I am using the subscript on $0$ to indicate the fiber so we can distinguish between $0_b$ and $0_{b'}$ as elements of $E$. Now $E = \bigsqcup_{b\in B} E_b = \bigsqcup_{b \in B} D(E_b) = D(E)$, and $E = D(E) = \bigsqcup_{b\in B}\{0_b\} = \{0_b \mid b \in B\}$ and the projection map $p : E \to B$ is nothing but $p(0_b) = b$.